# How do I store a string with multiple quotations mark in the data?

Tags: c#, string

I have an input which I need to store in string so that I can manipulate, but I am unable to store as string because the input has multiple quotations mark.

For example

```
string s = "dfasdf" : "FASDFSD" ["FSADFSA"];
```

Comment: Escaping them? `s = "\"dsa\" : \"dsad\" \"dfasdf\"";`

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to do it:

- Use a regular string and escape the double quotes, or
- Use a [verbatim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) `@""` string, and double the double quotes.

```
 "\"This string is quoted\""
```

or

```
 @"""This string is quoted"""
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just escape the quotation marks that should be treated as part of the data by writing `\"` instead of just `"`:

```
string s = "\"dfasdf\" : \"FASDFSD\" [\"FSADFSA\"]";
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to double each quotation mark literal you want in the string, as such:

```
string s = """dfasdf"":""FASDFSD""[""FSADFSA""]";
```

Another is to escape them:

```
string s ="\"dfasdf\":\"FASDFSD\"[\"FSADFSA\"]";
```

Answer (score 1):

Using escape is good:

```
    string s = "\"dfasdf\" : \"FASDFSD\" [\"FSADFSA\"]";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\"` in order to inject double quote

Answer (score 0):

You can include double quotes character in verbatim string(refer note below) by writing it twice

so if you need to store

```
hello "Hi!"
```

You need to store it like this

```
string s=@"hello ""Hi!"" ";
```

**OR**

escape it using `\`

```
string s="hello \"Hi!\" ";
```

---

**NOTE**

A verbatim string don't interpret control characters like \n,\r..So when \n,\r are used in verbatim strings,it is never interpreted.

So `string s="hello \n hi!";`

would be printed as

```
hello \n hi!
```

**not**

```
hello
hi!
```